# Security Claims in DBCommandInterceptor

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, authorization

i am currently using EF and .NET Core 3 through [Radzen](http://radzen.com) to build an application. This is working fine, but I want to add additional logging to the database. In order to do so, I would like to make use of the DBCommandInterceptor as shown [here](https://medium.com/aspnetcore/interception-in-entity-framework-core-862529b47f20) to do some post query commands.

Is it possible to get the Claims of the Microsoft Authorization in this Interceptor class? In my normal controller class, I can simply call

```
var userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
```

This doesn't work in the Interceptor and to be honest, my knowledge about that framework is very poor. I cannot even tell you why I can access the User reference in my ObjectController against the DBCommandInterceptor

Answer (score 0):

If you add the Interceptor in DbContext.OnConfiguring, you can pass any state to it you want.

So require your DbContext to accept an Identity, or with a service dependency it can use to access the user.  something like:

```
public class Db : DbContext
{
    ClaimsIdentity user;
    public Db(ClaimsIdentity user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }
```

Then configure the Interceptor to accept the User, or the DbContext instance.  eg

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;Database=EFCore3Test;Integrated Security = true", a => a.UseRelationalNulls(true))
                  .ConfigureWarnings(c => c.Log((RelationalEventId.CommandExecuting, LogLevel.Information)))
                  .UseLoggerFactory(MyLoggerFactory)
                  .AddInterceptors(new MyCommandInterceptor(this));

    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
}
```

And have the interceptor use the constructor argument:

```
public class MyCommandInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    private Db db;
    public MyCommandInterceptor(Db db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
    {
        var userId = db.user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
        //. . .
        return base.ReaderExecuting(command, eventData, result);
    }

}
```

Comment: How is variable user in Db initialized?